# simple set of differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can I write for a strictly convex, differentiable function $H$ from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$
H(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\frac{\partial{}H}{\partial{}x_{i}}(x)
$$
and if yes, why?

Comment: Not every strictly convex differentiable function is a solution of the linear PDE you wrote. Try to work out for example the case of $n=1$. In that case your PDE is just a linear first order ODE.

Comment: Thank you, yes. My function is also homogeneous, ie. H(kx)=kH(x). Perhaps that's the feature that results in this equation. I will look into it some more.

Comment: I suggest you to think in the simplest case $n = 1$. You will realise that there are not so many strictly convex functions which are also homogenous...

Comment: Yes, indeed. The above equation is a restatement of Euler's Theorem for homogeneous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $H(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\frac{\partial{}H}{\partial{}x_{i}}(x)$ is false ! An example is a constant function $H \ne 0$.

Comment: Under which circumstances is it correct (as one of many other possible solutions)? My $H$ is strictly convex, therefore not constant (I edited the question to reflect this important detail -- thank you, Fred!).

Comment: The above equation is a restatement of Euler's Theorem for homogeneous functions. Homogeneity (kH(x)=H(kx)) is required.